# How to compare BOOL and INTEGER in Netezza?

Tags: sql, casting, netezza

It seems odd that such a simple comparison is not automatically performed with implicit casting. I have tried,

1. `cast(1=1 as int) = 1` (Doesn't work)
2. `cast(cast(1 as INTX) as BOOL) = 1=1` where X=1,2,4,8; (Doesn't work)
3. `cast(1 as BOOL) = 1=1` strangely this works but I don't get what is the type of the 1 here.

Comment: So, the question is?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough, but my question is what is a short or simple way to compare an INT to a bool value. Right now I fixed this by converting the bool value to an INT explicitly with a case statement, like so, `1 = case when 1=1 then 1 else 0 end` where the LHS can be any integer column and the "1=1" can be any boolean column. This seems a bit ugly or nonintuitive to me. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think I can answer your question with a good deal of confidence: cast from INT to Boolean is not documented, therefore most likely not possible and at least not to be expected to be stable across versions.

See this: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_supported_im_ex_casts.html

Short of casting to-string and then to-int I see no other solution to the one you suggested (with various variations)

I find it strange too, but it seems to be what we will have to live with...